# Sharing web page as a file

Tags: macos, video, compatibility

I have a sort of "book" in the form of a web page.
It contains text, but also images *.JPG and videos *.MP4
I would like to make this a file that can be shared with others,
both Mac and Windows.  Is there a good way?  Can PDFs contain videos?
For example, can I
convert it to some "book" format that includes JPG and MP4
data?

TextEdit can save in *.rtfd format ... but Windows people won't be able to read it.
Safari can save as a *.webarchive ... but Windows people are excluded again.
Safari can export as PDF, but the result does not have working links, nor working videos.
Microsoft Word can save in a similar one-file *.mht format, but my experiments
show that MP4s don't go through.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put it on a webserver somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Cmd + S` (or `Ctrl + S` for windows) on a webpage in most browsers, it will 'save' the contents of the browser as well as (usually) a folder containing style and media information for that page. Then you can open that html file on any computer and it should open in the default browser, displaying whatever of the formatting it was able to save locally.

It will not preserve all of the websites functionality, depending on what the website was made with, but it preserves most to all of it.

Doing this might save your videos as well, depending on how you've embedded the videos.

There isn't going to be a one-size-fits all solution for this as web pages can contain an infinite number of media and formatting options which no other form of document (PDF, etc) can hope to replicate.

(Edit: You could also just host the webpage on some free website hosting platform and share the link)

Comment: I am accepting this answer.  Perhaps take all files used, and ZIP them together.  Best if orgainized as a flat directory, with no hierarchical subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer: *Convert to an ebook.*

The most common ebook format is [EPUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB).  Free apps exist (I used Calibre for my test) to convert from HTML to EPUB-format books.  The resulting ebook played flawlessly on my Mac using the Books app.

Drawback... The latest version of EPUB (3.2) supports ebooks contining embedded videos.  But most ebook readers do not support 3.2 .  So, if I use this method to distribute to Windows (and other) users, there would be an extra step where the recipient has to get a more recent ebook reader.